# Execute gradle task with environment value

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline and one of my step is input that I can provide some option. I create environment for this option to use it in another step. Another step means executing gradle task when name is conneceted with env value

```
env.OPTION = input message: 'Option', parameters: [string(name: 'Option', defaultValue: 'Value1', description: 'Value1/Value2')]
```

then I would like to have something like this:

```
sh './gradlew buildValue1'
```

Is there any option to do this that way:

```
sh './gradlew build+${env.OPTION}'
```

Comment: Please remove the solution from your question and instead add it as an answer (and accept it).

Answer (score 1):

Solution, replace ' with " and remove +

```
sh "./gradlew build${env.OPTION}"
```